# Prevent overflow with li elements containing images

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I wish to display a `ul` that has a maximum of three `li` on each row. Each `li` contains  a vertically centered image with an equal width, so I thought this would be easy. However, I can't stop it from overflowing:

[image]

Instead, I'd like the fourth image to clear to a new line. Here's my code:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="1.jpg"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="2.jpg"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="3.jpg"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="4.jpg"></a></li>
</ul>​

ul {
    border-spacing: 2px;
    width: 150px;
    background: red;
}

li {
    height: 48px;
    background: #000;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
img {
    width: 48px;
    display:block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}​
```

How can I resolve this?

UPDATE: Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UvnK5/4/) with a clearer example.

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net for us to play with?

Comment: Maybe adding `overflow:hidden` to `ul`?

Comment: Your `ul` has width 150px, your `li` is 48px. 48*4=192? It's going to overflow...

Comment: @JuanMendes I'm trying to get the fourth image to clear to a new line.

Comment: Using `display: table-cell` forces all adjacent elements with the same property/value to display within an anonymous table-row.  Just like ordinary table rows/cells, these elements will not wrap.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UvnK5/6/ edited your jsfiddle..is that fine with you.? the way the fourth element is going back down?

Comment: @praveen the images are sadly no longer vertically centered.

Comment: flexbox model would have done that in a cleaner way but u ll compromise compatibility. trying for something. :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting overflow?

```
ul {
    border-spacing: 2px;
    width: 150px;
    background: red;
    overflow-x:hidden
}
```

To have the "overflow" move to the next row, make your UL as wide as the three images, use float:left on your li and set the width of your li.

```
ul {
    width:400px;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

ul li {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did try that, but it just hides the fourth image. I'm instead looking for it to go to the next line.

Comment: I've made an edit. You can see how it works here: http://preview.moveable.com/jm/slideshow/

Answer (score 0):

Tell the `li`s to float http://jsfiddle.net/8Pvtb/1/

```
li {


   height: 48px;
    background: #000;
    display:table-cell;
    float: left;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border-spacing: 12px;
}
```

But I don't understand why you want `display:table-cell`, it's not. I would use `inline-block`

http://jsfiddle.net/8Pvtb/5/

```
ul {
    border-spacing: 2px;
    width: 155px;
    background: red;
}

li {
    height: 48px;
    background: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border-spacing: 12px;
}
img {
    width: 48px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}​
```

Comment: Almost! But now the image is no longer vertically centered.

Comment: What do you mean? How can they be centered on two lines? They do look centered to me, post a picture of what you're looking for

Comment: Each image should be centered within it's containing li. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HHUQ3/) with your example, which unfortunately doesn't achieve that. Sorry if I wasn't entirely clear.

Comment: @Jonathan Initially you were asking about getting them in a new line, now you're morphing your question, SO works best when you ask one question per post

Comment: Juan, the code in my question always vertically centered the images.

Comment: @Jonathan Are all images the same size? Can you just add margin to the top of the images? http://jsfiddle.net/UvnK5/11/